# Generalize $\pi_0(B\mathcal{C})\cong\{\text{objects}\}/\{\text{morphisms}\}$ to categories internal to topological spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

**Warmup:**

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an ordinary category. Denote by $$B\mathcal{C}=(\coprod_{i\in\mathbb{N_0}}N_{i}(\mathcal{C})\times\Delta^i)/\tilde{}$$ its classifying space, i.e. the geometric realization of it's nerve. The description $$\pi_0(B\mathcal{C})\cong\{\text{objects in }\mathcal{C}\}/\{\text{morphisms in }\mathcal{C}\}$$ is well known, but as I could not find a proof in the literature and as it will illustrates my question, a proof will follow:

Let $(x_0\rightarrow ...\rightarrow x_i,\lambda)\in N_{i}(\mathcal{C})\times\Delta^i$ be a representative of a point in $B\mathcal{C}$. As $\Delta^i$ is path-connected, we can connect $\lambda$ to $(1,0,...,0)$ and get a path from $[(x,\lambda)]$ to $[(x_0\rightarrow ...\rightarrow x_i,(1,0,...,0)]=[(x_0,1)]$. This shows that every path component has a 0-simplex as a representative. Now take a path $\gamma$ in $B\mathcal{C}$ which connects two points $[(x_0,1)], [(x_1,1)]$. Since $B\mathcal{C}$ is a CW-complex, the relative cellular approximation theorem yields a path between the same points in the 1-skeleton, but as $N_{1}(\mathcal{C})$ is discrete, it is constant. Thinking about which points of $N_1(\mathcal{C})\times\Delta^1$ got identified in the 1-skeleton, one concludes that there is a zig-zag of morphisms between $x_0$ and $x_1$.

**The question:**

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a category internal to topological spaces, then it's nerve is a simplicial space and one can take the geometric realization of this simplicial space to obtain the topological classifying space $B\mathcal{D}$ of $\mathcal{D}$. Be aware of the fact, that this space does not have to be a CW-complex.

Now, is there a similar simple description of $\pi_0(B\mathcal{D})$ like in the discrete case? Maybe in terms of $\pi_0(Ob(\mathcal{D}))$ and $\pi_0(Mor(\mathcal{D}))$?

Comment: How exactly is the quotient (objects)/(morphisms) being defined? Do you mean to indicate that two objects $x$ and $y$ are equivalent if there exists $f:x \to y$? Or maybe $f:y \to x$? Or either?

Comment: Neither: two objects become identified if there is a zigzag of morphisms connecting them.

Comment: Exactly. Compare http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+category

Comment: Morally, $\pi_0 (B \mathcal{D})$ should be the coequaliser of $\pi_0 (\operatorname{mor} \mathcal{D}) \rightrightarrows \pi_0 (\operatorname{ob} \mathcal{D})$; however, $\pi_0 : \mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$ is not a left adjoint unless $\mathbf{Top}$ means something like locally connected spaces.

Comment: I would accept to restrict to categories $\mathcal{D}$ which objects and morphisms are locally connected or other convenient point-set topological restrictions, as long as all the constructions (taking pullbacks for the nerve, etc.) find place in the category of all topological spaces, since I don't want to get another space $B\mathcal{D}$ by changing the topological category.

Comment: @ZhenLin The nLab (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+space#locally_connected_spaces) says locally connected spaces form a coreflective subcategory. Does that help to conclude your statement if $ob\mathcal{D}$ and $mor\mathcal{D}$ are assumed to be locally connected?

Comment: For the argument I was thinking of, I really want $\pi_0 : \mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$ to be a left Quillen functor. But perhaps we can work around that problem by first passing through the Quillen equivalence $\mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{sSet}$.

Comment: The proof you give is not correct. Consider the category $x\rightarrow y\leftarrow z$. There is a path in $B\mathcal{C}$ from $x$ to $z$, but there is no morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ from $x$ to $z$. This contradicts your claim "which means that there is a morphism between x0 and x1"; the mistake seems to be in the earlier claim "yields a path ... but as $N_1(\mathcal{C})$ is discrete, it is constant". As Zhen Lin points out, the correct deduction is that there is a zigzag of morphisms from $x_0$ to $x_1$.

Comment: Of course you are right. Thanks. The path is one in the one skeleton of $B(\mathcal{C})$ in which some identifications took place like $[(x\rightarrow y),(0,1)]=[(z\rightarrow y),(1,0)]$ in your example. One can figure out that iterations of this case are the only thing which can happen, so we get a zig-zag as desired.

Comment: Any equivalence relation $R$ on any topological space $X$ gives rise to a topological category $\mathcal C$ (in fact, groupoid with trivial automorphism groups) such that $\pi_0(B(\mathcal C))$ is $\pi_0(X/R)$. I think this means that even if $X$ is locally connected, situation might be pathological because of $R$...

Answer (score 1):

If everything takes place in the category of compactly generated spaces, it holds $$\pi_0(BC)=\pi_0(obC)/\tilde{},$$ where two path components in the object space get identified, if there are objects in each of them respectively which are connected by a morphism in the category and $\tilde{}$ is the equivalence relation generated by that.

This follows from Lemma 11.11 in Peter May's ['The Geometry of Iterated Loop Spaces'](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.170.2840&rep=rep1&type=pdf), in which the more general claim for simplicial spaces is proven.